# Trigger / queue build policy pipeline on ADO PR with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

In a repository on Azure DevOps (ADO), I have a build validation policy on my main branch that PRs which wish to merge into main must first complete a successful Azure pipeline run.

I would like to use the Azure CLI to trigger this build validation pipeline.

I know that I can trigger this pipeline with `az pipelines run` or `az pipelines build queue`, and point to my PR with the `--branch` argument as eg. `az pipelines build queue --branch "refs/pull/123/merge" --definition-id 456`.

However, when I do so, the pipeline run doesn't count towards the PR's build validation. That is, even if my pipeline succeeds, it is not reflected in my PR, and I still can't merge my changes.

How can I trigger my pipeline with the Azure CLI, so that it counts towards my PR's build validation? I am looking for the Azure CLI equivalent to clicking the "Queue" button on my PR's pipeline (image taken from [this comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/735#issuecomment-1311801964)):

[image: Queue button on ADO PR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `az repos pr policy` command group to achieve this.

Start by determining the build validation evaluation ID associated with your PR. Note that this value changes on a *per* PR basis.

You can determine this value for your PR with:

```bash
az repos pr policy list --id <YOUR-PR-NUMBER-HERE> --query "[?configuration.type.displayName=='Build'].evaluationId"
```

Your evaluation ID will be a long alpha-numeric string, separated with hyphens. It'll look something like: `d2hr35yd-9fe0-y4t5-hb35-5een2cr04b2`.

You then need to pass this value to `az repos pr policy queue` as eg.

```bash
az repos pr policy queue --evaluation-id <BUILD-EVAL-ID-HERE> --id <YOUR-PR-NUMBER-HERE>
```

Putting these two steps together, and doing a little string manipulation to make things work, gives us:

```bash
# Your PR number here
pr_id=123

build_pipeline_eval_id=$(
  az repos pr policy list \
      --id $pr_id \
      --query "[?configuration.type.displayName=='Build'].evaluationId | [0]" \
      --out tsv
)
az repos pr policy queue --evaluation-id $build_pipeline_eval_id --id $pr_id
```

This will now run your required build pipeline, against your PR, as if you had clicked the "Queue" button from the ADO UI, as desired.

Comment: Glad that you have figured out the answer. Maybe, you can mark yourself answer as solution of this case. This could be helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.